# Access native handles of Pyqt in C++

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, pybind11

How can I get the pointer to the objects  created in PyQt such that I can use them in the C++/Qt app? The python interpreter is running embedded using pybind11.

Goal is to be able to borrow settings widgets created in python plugins using pyqt and show them embedded in the settings widget of the core app.

Comment: Are those widgets added to a parent created in C++? If so, you could just use child events (override the `childEvent` or install an event filter for `ChildPolished`); then, if you also need access to "grandchild" widgets created in python, use object names.

Comment: Atm nothing is added, because I dont know how.